# Is there a way to close a modal using Back button without tampering browser history states?

Tags: javascript, angular, browser-history

I have a rather specific use case.

Imagine I navigate from **Page A** to **Page B** (adds one history state). On Page B then I interact with the page by opening a modal. But the modal is implemented in a way that it closes when browser back button is clicked.

when modal is opened:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        history.pushState(null, null, this.pageBHomeUrl + "?modal");
    }
```

and when it's closed the modal state is replaced with the previous home url:

```
close(): void {
        history.replaceState(null, null, this.pageBHomeUrl);
    }
```

When I close the modal, my browser history looks like this (most recent first)

- pageBHomeUrl
- pageA

However, I want to make sure that I can close the modal **while keeping Page A as the most recent history state**... Is there a way to delete pageBHomeUrl history state or move pageA state forward? Or close a modal using a back button without changing history states?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you navigate from A to B, your history looks like this:

- pageA
- pageBHomeUrl *- current*

When you open the modal and call `pushState`, your history will look like this:

- pageA
- pageBHomeUrl
- pageBHomeUrl?modal *- current*

When you then close the modal using the button and call `replaceState`, your history will look like this:

- pageA
- pageBHomeUrl
- pageBHomeUrl *- current*

This is not what you want. Instead of `replaceState`, use `popState` in the `close` handler to get back from the modal to the desired history:

- pageA
- pageBHomeUrl *- current*

Comment: How can I do that? If I don't know the specific URL of `pageA` (query params etc can change so it can't be hard-coded)... Also there are multiple modals on the page, each of whom will essentially create a new `pageBHomeUrl` state after closing.

Comment: You don't need to know anything about `pageA` in your modal code, that's totally unrelated. If your issue is that you want to go "back" from `pageBHomeUrl?modal` to a *different* `pageBHomeUrl` than before opening the modal (which I really wouldn't recommend from a UX perspective), then use `popState` followed by `replaceState`.

Comment: I want to be able to go to `pageA` by clicking the Back button only once after I close the modal(s). So essentially I want to ensure that every time `pageBHomeUrl` is the *current* state, when I click Back button, then I will go to `pageA` instead of the previous `pageBHomeUrl`. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's what I was saying all the way long, just not as verbose :-)

Comment: @hi, did the accepted answer worked for you? I try to do same thing but it seems that pageBHomeUrl?modal from example remains in the history.

Comment: @Bergi I applied your approach(second comment) and it's worked. Thanks for this 